# Help with URL as InputSource

Tags: java, android, xpath

So I have been asking questions here trying to get the answer for myself but I just cant get it to work without running into a new error.  If anyone can help me I would appreciate it.  I want to replace this portion

```
"<a>\n" + 
"<b>\n" + 
"<c id=\"00001\" time=\"1:00\" day=\"Friday\" name1=\"John\" name2=\"Mary\"></c>\n" + 
"<c id=\"00002\" time=\"2:00\" day=\"Monday\" name1=\"Ed\" name2=\"Kate\"></c>\n" + 
"<c id=\"00003\" time=\"3:00\" day=\"Sunday\" name1=\"Mary\" name2=\"Ed\"></c>\n" + 
"<c id=\"00004\" time=\"4:00\" day=\"Friday\" name1=\"Kate\" name2=\"John\"></c>\n" + 
"</b>\n" + 
"</a>"
```

with a XML url instead, as that information will be pulled from a server as the data changes.

Here is the source as you can see what I am trying accomplish once I have the data from the xml file.  It works fine as it is, but whenever I try and implement a url as the InputSource I get tons of errors that no matter what ive tried does not resolve the problem.

```
package com.newxpath;

import java.io.StringReader;

import javax.xml.xpath.XPath;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPathConstants;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPathExpressionException;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPathFactory;

import org.w3c.dom.NamedNodeMap;
import org.w3c.dom.Node;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class NewxpathActivity extends Activity {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);


    InputSource xml = new InputSource(new StringReader("<a>\n" + 
            "<b>\n" + 
            "<c id=\"00001\" time=\"1:00\" day=\"Friday\" name1=\"John\" name2=\"Mary\"></c>\n" + 
            "<c id=\"00002\" time=\"2:00\" day=\"Monday\" name1=\"Ed\" name2=\"Kate\"></c>\n" + 
            "<c id=\"00003\" time=\"3:00\" day=\"Sunday\" name1=\"Mary\" name2=\"Ed\"></c>\n" + 
            "<c id=\"00004\" time=\"4:00\" day=\"Friday\" name1=\"Kate\" name2=\"John\"></c>\n" + 
            "</b>\n" + 
            "</a>"));

    String name = "Ed";

    XPath xpath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();
    String expr = String.format("//a/b/c[@name2='%s']", name);
    Node c = null;
    try {
        c = (Node) xpath.evaluate(expr, xml, XPathConstants.NODE);
    } catch (XPathExpressionException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    NamedNodeMap attribs = c.getAttributes();
    String id = attribs.getNamedItem("id").getNodeValue();
    String time = attribs.getNamedItem("time").getNodeValue();
    // etc.

    EditText id2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.id2);
    EditText time2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.time2);

    id2.setText(String.valueOf(id));
    time2.setText(String.valueOf(time));

}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably need to add the INTERNET permission to your AndroidManifest.xml file (I assume from the Android imports that this is taking place on Android). Otherwise I don't see why this wouldn't work. I copied your XML to the URL http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=RF8cL5YZ and then ran it against the following code at a command line and it worked just fine.

```
import java.io.StringReader;

import javax.xml.xpath.XPath;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPathConstants;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPathExpressionException;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPathFactory;

import org.w3c.dom.NamedNodeMap;
import org.w3c.dom.Node;

import org.xml.sax.InputSource;
import java.net.*;

public class test
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {
    URL url = new URL("http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=RF8cL5YZ");
    InputSource xml = new InputSource(url.openStream());
    String name = "Ed";

    XPath xpath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();
    String expr = String.format("//a/b/c[@name2='%s']", name);
    Node c = null;
    try {
        c = (Node) xpath.evaluate(expr, xml, XPathConstants.NODE);
    } catch (XPathExpressionException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    NamedNodeMap attribs = c.getAttributes();
    String id = attribs.getNamedItem("id").getNodeValue();
    String time = attribs.getNamedItem("time").getNodeValue();
    // etc.

    System.out.println("["+String.valueOf(id)+"]["+String.valueOf(time)+"]");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for responding, for some reason it still wont work it just force closes when I try and test it (force closes on my android phone that is)  And I have the uses internet permission added.  I attempted to use your code that looks cleaned up quite a bit and get the same problem.

Comment: Look at the android log output and paste the error code generated in there.

Comment: None were listed as errors but filtering I found this warning 09-22 00:23:30.435: WARN/ActivityManager(1618): Activity idle timeout for HistoryRecord{4084da58 com.newxpath/.NewxpathActivity}

Comment: You may not strictly speaking recognize the exception trace, but if you got a force close then you got an exception. Run `adb logcat` at a command line and then run the app, and you should see the exception being thrown.

Comment: D/AndroidRuntime( 4963): Shutting down VM
W/dalvikvm( 4963): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d5a0)
E/AndroidRuntime( 4963): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime( 4963): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.newxpath/com.newxpath.NewxpathActivity}:

Comment: Ok I got it running, but it still is not displaying the requested data from xml